# Is it possible to change windows default shortcut Functions

Tags: winapi, windows-explorer, windows-shortcut

I want to know whether it is possible to Windows default shortcuts functions.

We know that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> is used to search in windows explorer. But I want to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to trigger my application which will give more advanced options to search.

I want <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> should open my application within windows explorer only and not in entire computer.
I dont want to alter the any other keys functions except <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

Is it possible ? If yes how ?

Please help.

Comment: Did you try to use RegisterHotKey function?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have decided to use AHK,

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class CabinetWClass

^f::
Run "C:\myapp.exe"
return

#IfWinActive  ; turn off context sensitivity
```